# Функция для фильтрации массива

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

Есть ли такая встроенная функция в php, которая примет в аргументы набор ключей и отфильтрует массив, отбросив все значения которые не совпадают с указанным набором ключей?

```html
<?php 
$original = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3];
$keys = [0, 2, 5];
/*magic function...*/
$new = [-3, -1, 2]; /*result*/
```

Comment: надо использовать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php  и сортировка тут не причём

Comment: @СергейМишин можете подсказать callback функцию для этой задачи?

Comment: давайте так. я вам дал удочку, а вы ловите рыбу. Если не получается её применить - вот с той проблемой и приходите)

Comment: @СергейМишин хорошо, справедливо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одной такой функции нет, но две есть :))

```
print_r(array_intersect_key($original,array_flip($keys)));
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7820aca0960f4b663bc7f77d616dab0f65a2b181)

Comment: Это очень хитрое и ёмкое решение! Но не является ли такой подход костыльством?

Comment: в чем, собственно, костыль. функция специально придумана, чтоб отбирать нужные индексы, мы этим и пользуемся. Даже если не все значения в массиве ключей не уникальные, то отбрасывание повторов смысл не изменяет. вроде, все корректно

Comment: ну я конкретно про комбинирование array_intersect_key и array_flip . Но видимо не костыльно, потому как все по пути наименьшего сопротивления.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <?php 
    $original = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3];
    $keys = [0, 2, 5];
    function thisIsMagick($originals,$keys){
            foreach($keys as $key){
                var_dump($originals[$key]);   
            }
    }

    thisIsMagick($original,$keys);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b755ad31223ddf3bd2f90e2ab29da29b4781c92

Comment: Получается чтоб получить новый массив с отфильтрованными значениями, нужно объявить еще одну переменную с пустым массивом и туда пушить значения из цикла?

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4409b3a425349f5e7cd07c20198edc54baad7494

Comment: С return не подходит так как возвращается только первое подходящее значение.